# Dividing an ArrayList and passing it to different threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I'm trying to divide an ArrayList into multiple threads so they may later execute a RMI call. However, even before any RMI begins, I'm having trouble passing the subList as an argument. The output of the following program is:

```
get(1): 28.833612828660367
get(1): 28.833612828660367
```

Whereas I'd expect the numbers to be different. This means each thread is receiving the exact same array. I don't know much of Java, so what could possibly be the problem?

In the code below, N is the number of total elements in the array and K is the number of threads the program should launch.

```
package rmi;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Client {

    private static final int N = 10;
    private static final int K = 2;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Double> vector = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            vector.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1, 100));
        }

        for (int i=0; i<K; i++){
            new ClientThread(vector.subList(i*N/K, i*N/K+N/K-1)).start();
        }
    }

}


class ClientThread extends Thread{

    private static List<Double> vector;

    public ClientThread(List<Double> vectorArg){
        vector = vectorArg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Service s = (Service) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Servico");
            System.out.println("get(1): "+vector.get(1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this arrangement. Instead of splitting the list, could you use a thread safe collection which each thread could then get the data from?

Comment: I tried making an ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> (best thing I could think of - a list of lists), and passing each independent array to each thread. The result was the same. Could it maybe have to do with the way the random numbers are being generated?

Comment: The idea behind the program is to allow the array to be processed in parallel through a RMI call within each thread, speeding up the process. That part was abstracted from the code above.

Comment: You could use a concurrent queue shared between the threads for achieving the same. The sublist partitioning doesn't look quite correct at the moment.

Comment: You're right, I think that would work. However, I'd probably have to worry about synchronizing the access to the queue, correct? I might try that but would love to understand why the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove static from the field `vector` of `ClientThread` class

```
class ClientThread extends Thread {

    private List<Double> vector;

    public ClientThread(List<Double> vectorArg) {
        vector = vectorArg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Service s = (Service) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Servico");
            System.out.println("get(1): " + vector.get(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```